# red5: mixing files when recording at same time

Tags: red5

I use red5 1.01 and record video1 to webapps/live (I tried also to /vod)

I open browser1 and it records fine to /live/streams/video1.flv

I record video2 with pc2 to webapps/live

Works fine as well: I have /live/streams/video2.flv

Problem comes when I try to record video1 from PC1 and video2 from PC2 at the same time:
video1 is blank, video2 has video1 content:

RED5 totally mixes and overwrites the 2 streams. It looks like it cannot record 2 streams at the same time (the 2 streams has different names of course)

Regards

Comment: Use a newer build and try again; I suggest 1.0.5

Comment: yes ! that worked ! (from 1.04)

Comment: awesome; glad to help